# Audio download link works in Firefox but streams in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, audio, download, streaming, mp3

I've setup a download link on the site I'm building so that when users sign up to the musicians mailing list they can download a track for free. With this current code:

`<a  href="http://samsouth.com/audio/Mind.mp3">click here to download</a>`

It works in Firefox when you click the link it opens a window asking if you'd like to download but in Chrome it streams the track. If I change the file to .ogg then the reverse happens - I can download in Chrome but it streams in Firefox. Guess this is happening because I'm providing a format that the browser is capable of streaming. So how do I stop it streaming? can I provide two href's?

Having looked for similar questions here I came across the html5 attribute which can be added to links `download="filename.mp3"` I've tried this:

```
<a  href="http://samsouth.com/audio/Mind.mp3" download="Mind.mp3">click here to download</a>
```

But still it keeps streaming in Chrome, any ideas? help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you zip the file? that'll avoid the streaming.

**OTHER OPTION**

Other option a little of PHP :

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
?>
```

and then

```
<a href="direct_download.php?file=FILENAME.mp3">Download the mp3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code?

```
<a href="http://test.com/path/to/my/file.mp3" download="true">download</a>
```

I think, it will work on all browsers.